# rxplot euler from gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i want to plot the orientation of my quadrotor in euler and not in quaterion. is there a opportunity (message) how i can get the angels in euler from gazebo?

thankgs,regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30330/rxplot-euler-from-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar need so I wrote a simple Python node that does this for the quaternion in nav_msgs/Odometry messages. It allows you to select the Euler rotation convention and will also optionally output the Euler angles in degrees. If you want to take a look it's called quat_to_ypr.py in the starmac_tools package (starmac_common stack).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rotations in ROS are always communicated as Quaternions. You will need to convert them by hand. TF uses Bullet internally which has utility methods to convert to and from Euler angles. See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/RotationMethods).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1